# R : How to use self-defined function with outer

Tags: r

I'm new to R.
I have this simple function that takes 2 arguments and returns the bigger one.

```
> z
function (x,y) 
{
ifelse (x>y, out<- x, out<- y)
return(out)
}
```

I tested the function with combinations like z(1,3), z(6,2), all gives the correct answer.
However I got the wrong results when I use the function with outer.

```
> outer(x,y, FUN="z")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5`
```

Any idea where's the error?

Many thanks.

Comment: `ifelse (x>y, out<- x, out<- y)` is better written `out <- ifelse (x > y, x, y)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `Vectorize`

```
outer(x,y, FUN=Vectorize(z))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    5
#[3,]    3    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    4    4    5
```

We can also get the same result using `pmax`

```
outer(x,y, FUN=pmax)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    5
#[3,]    3    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    4    4    5
```

The corresponding elements that occupy the matrix would be

```
outer(x,y, FUN=paste)
#    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
#[1,] "1 2" "1 3" "1 4" "1 5"
#[2,] "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5"
#[3,] "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5"
#[4,] "4 2" "4 3" "4 4" "4 5"
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 2:5
```

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thanks for the support.

Comment: Congrats akrun.  Your 100-thousandth point almost came on your 4000th answer.  So close!  Nice work.

Comment: @akrun congratulations!